# Как отправить сразу несколько картинок с помощью messages.send | VK_API Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Всем привет! Делаю бота, нужно отправить 2 картинки сразу. Пишу их через запятую:

```
attachment = 'photo185014513_324290064, photo185014513_344406321'
```

но отправляется только первая картинка.

Что я делаю не так?

```
vk.messages.send(
        random_id   =   get_random_id(),
        peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
        message     =   'Heh'
        attachment = 'photo185014513_324290064, photo185014513_344406321'
)
```

Comment: Возможно нет доступа к одной из картинок.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie т.е. по моему, как я предположил, работать должно?

Comment: @TimohaTimohavich, по идее все правильно

Comment: Попробуйте `attachment = [ 'photo185014513_324290064', 'photo185014513_344406321' ]`

Comment: @МихаилМуругов вот теперь работает :). Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

```
attachment = [ 'photo185014513_324290064', 'photo185014513_344406321' ]
```

В методах `vk_api` следует передавать объекты без преобразований. Т.е. если нужно передать целое значение - передаём `int`, если нужен список чего-либо, передаём `list`, а дальше либа сама переделает их в нужную строку для передачи на сервер. Вообще, в случае вопросов, советую смотреть исходники либы: https://github.com/python273/vk_api